# Excel: how to deal with mixed date / non-date formats?

Tags: excel

I have been working with Excel for a long time, so I was surprised not to find a solution to this problem myself. I hope that some of you will able to help me, however:

I extracted data from a database. One of the variables I am looking at contains dates. However, these dates came in mixed formats. For instance:

```
Incorporation data
2014 (formatted as text)
01.01.2012 (formatted as date)
21/08/1996 (formatted as text)
...
```

My problem is now the following:

If I apply the formula `YEAR()` , I get wrong values for cells containing just years and formatted as text or for cells containing dates but not formatted as such. If I use `RIGHT()` to extract the year, I get wrong values for cells formatted as dates as the underlying values are in Excel date format.

Is there a way to deal with this? It would already help if I could just copy and hard paste the dates how they are shown and not the underlying Excel date value.

Best,
Martin

Comment: Why can't you copy paste cell displayed text? You don't show the code you tried and what results are

Comment: @dbmitch I tried copy paste, but the problem is that then Excel copies the date-formatted cells not as displayed but the underlying numeric code for that very date.

Comment: Copy paste in VBA. You can make your own macro. Check the various paste options with right click

Comment: To extract the year (as a number), the following will cover the 3 scenarios you've listed: `=IFERROR(IF(AND(LEN(A1)=4,NOT(ISNUMBER(A1))),A1*1,YEAR(A1)),RIGHT(A1,4)*1)`. Not posted as an answer though because it's hacky and doesn't cover every possible format.

Comment: tried `datevalue()` ?